# Предлог о/об

Tags: предлог

Как будет правильно - "о учениках или об учениках"?

Comment: @suzana, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 4):

Правильно (= лучше): ***об учениках.*** См. http://gramota.ru/spravka/letters/?rub=ko_dnu :

> **в предложном падеже** перед
> словами, начинающимися **гласными**,
> употребляется предлог **об**:
> *вспоминать об отце; задуматься об учебе.*

Из Горбачевича ("Трудности словоупотребления и варианты норм русского литературного языка".  Л., 1974):

> Предлог **о** употребляется перед
> словами с начальным согласным или
> йотированным гласным звуком,
> обозначаемым буквами  **ё, ю, я…**
> Перед гласными нейотированными предлог
> **о** употреблять **не рекомендуется**.

Comment: Я тоже выбрала об,основываясь на правило-"перед глас-ми употр-ся об" Но возникла полемика))

Comment: Ну а в чём суть полемики? Кто-то утверждает, что неправильно говорить "об учениках"? Или же считает допустимым и вариант "о учениках"?

Comment: Да попытались доказать, что во множ. числе допустимо и "о". Русский для меня не родной, и я подумала, может, в грамматических правилах какие-то изменения произошли, я не знаю. )))